# Delphi 7 циклы с заданным числом повторений

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, pascal, delphi-7

Как написать такую программу? Насколько я понял- получится 2 Begin, и 3 переменные, которые нужно задать пользователю,но как написать все правильно-без понятия
Задание:
Выведите таблицу значений функции y = x^3 при изменении x в интервале от A до B с шагом H.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses Math;
var
    x,y,h: real;
begin
    Writeln('Input X: ');
  Readln (x);
  Writeln ('Input H: ');
  Readln (h);

    while x <= 1 do begin
        y := x*x*x;
        writeln(x:4:1,' | ',y:5:2);
    readln;
        x:=x + h;
    Writeln ('X=',x, 'Y=',y);
    Readln;
    end;
end.
```

Получилось так, но не уверен что правильно

Comment: Это очень базовый вопрос. То, что вы не нашли на него ответ, означает, что вы его просто не искали. Попробуйте самостоятельно решить вашу задачу, и если будут вопросы по уже вами написаннному коду, тогда и приходите.

Comment: Осталось ввести верхний предел и использовать его вместо `< 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  x,y,b,h: real;
begin
  Write('Input A: '); 
  ReadLn(x); // т.к. X меняется от A до B, то сразу читаем X = A
  Write('Input B: ');
  ReadLn(b);
  Write('Input H: ');
  ReadLn(h);
  while x <= b do 
  begin
    y := x * x * x; // можно y := Power(x, 3);
    WriteLn('X = ', x:4:1, ' Y = ', y:5:2);
    x := x + h;
    // ReadLn; - опционально, для остановки после каждой строчки
  end;
end.
```